# Using the iPad dock connector to connect cameras - airplane mode - no WiFi

Tags: ipad, ios, webcam, lightning

At my work we need to connect to a few IP cameras but it can not be wireless as the iPad must be in airplane mode, we must use the 30 pin dock connector and a wired cable.

We are installing cameras in the cabin on an aircraft and need to view it on the iPads on the flight deck. But certification rules will not allow us to use WiFi for this.

We are open to becoming enterprise developers because the software will be on a couple of thousand iPads.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify some of your constraints:
1) If you're not using wireless, how are you connecting the iPads to the network? Are they allowed to be wireless, just not the IP cameras?
2) Are you trying to setup a front end to the IP cameras to control # of people who connect to them?

Comment: We are installing cameras in the cabin on an aircraft and need to view it on the iPads on the flight deck. But certification rules will not allow us to use WiFi for this.

Comment: We will have a couple of thousand iPads so I understand we can use the Enterprice opportunity Apple gives and that gives us grater possibilities with regards to the app calling private API:s. Am I right?

Comment: Cub71 - As an enterprise user you can make whatever apps you want, sign them and they run. You don't need approval to use private API because you don't enter them into the public App Store - just knowledge and a little money for the yearly certificates.

Answer (score 2):

Using the iPad camera connector with the USB port seems to work with certain items (headsets, etc.) that aren't cameras, leading me to believe that there is a full USB hardware implementation in there but there simply aren't any drivers. If this is true, you could get a USB Ethernet dongle, write iPad drivers for it in your camera-viewing app, and use Ethernet to connect to your cameras. I doubt that would get on the App Store, but that's not a problem, given that you will be using the Enterprise distribution method. This might also preclude charging the iPad while it is connected, so you may have to design and manufacture your own power-and-ethernet dongle.

Answer (score 0):

There are ethernet connectible cameras out there (DLink makes some, D-Link DCS-1000 for example), that will give you an ip address (and or port) to it's internal webserver that you will be able to hit (I do the same for my home security camera).

http://www.nextag.com/ethernet-camera/shop-html for an example list.

Comment: But how to connect the iPad to the network via the cable? Do you have an app that handles that? We can't use WiFi.

Comment: The iPad doesn't have any ethernet cable and only uses Wi-Fi or 3G network.

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about live video here? Then I'm pretty confident that you are out of luck (assuming that blutooth isn't an option either).

- Factor one is the issue already mentioned: No hardware or drivers to connect to.
- Factor two is the lack of Apple frameworks supporting such a setup, so development becomes quite expensive
- Factor three - and IMO the final nail in the coffin - is the limited input bandwidth of the iPad connector.. It is good for some audio, but it's simply not enough for video input.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Wi-Fi or 3G, then you **have** to use the camera connection kit. You can insert an SD-card or just use the USB port